# why is it that we can't use ArrayList.get(-1) to get the last element of the ArrayList in java? it works in python though

Tags: java, arraylist

```
ArrayList.get(-1) // why it will not return the last element?
```

Comment: Because Java isn't Python.

Comment: Java doesn't work Python way.

Comment: `ArrayList.get(ArrayList.size()-1)` is what you're looking for. However, you must be sure that the ArrayList is not empty or else you will run into errors.

Comment: ah awesome! thank you! another question is supposedly got one array list which contains another array list. is it possible to find an element in the internal array list using array list.get(i).get(j) with use of for loops too @turbo

Comment: Somewhat more sophisticated syntax, not neccessarily `-1`, would really not be bad at all with Java 8. You will miss `ArrayList::getLast()` when chaining methods together.

Comment: Yes that should work, you can also use `for (ArrayList arraylistInner : arraylistOuter) { for (Element e : arraylistInner) { /*code*/ } }`

Comment: Yes, Why don't you try it?

Comment: thank you! there are some bugs in my code. ah using enhanced for loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, *Java* is not *Python* (although [Jython](http://jython.org/) implements *Python* in *Java*). Second, you should read the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29) on ArrayList - that is it throws an `Exception`,

```
IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index >= size())
```

Finally, you can do this

```
myList.get(myList.size() - 1);
```

to get this last element in your `List` (e.g. `myList`).

Answer (score 2):

If you want that behaviour:

```
List<T> snake = new ArrayList<>(){
    @Override
    public T get(int i) {
        return super.get((i + size()) % size());
   }
};
```

This will work for any value of i.

Answer (score 0):

Not answering why it is not possible, as that is not in the scope of StackOverflow.

However, it is possible in the following way when using Java 8:

`Optional<E> optE = eCollection.stream().reduce((previous, current) -> current);`

And if it exists, you can get it via `optE.get()`, once you have tested presence with `optE.isPresent()`.

However, I am pretty sure this incurs a performance penalty as you are reducing the stream, while you really just want to inspect the last value.

I have some hopes it will be added in Java 9, if enough people complain when using Java 8. Because in my example you cannot do it as easy as getting the first element, which would be:

`Optional<E> optE = eCollection.stream().findFirst()`.

**Edit**, also note for practical purposes that other operations proceed the `findFirst()` call. For example a `filter()` call.